# amp-story is already registered. The script tag for amp-story is likely included twice in the page

Tags: javascript, amp-html, amp-story, amp-stories

I have a project where I'm trying to build an amp-story generator with a simple editor. You can check the current state at https://ampy.co/test/.

The idea is when you insert information on the left panel, the amp-story to be rebuild within an iframe element.

This works only in firefox, but fails in every other browser. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying here?

Steps to reproduce:

- Open https://ampy.co/test/
- Open console (dev tools)
- Click add layer, or add page on the left panel
  [image: Image of the left panel]
- Check the console log for all the errors such as "amp-story is already registered. The script tag for amp-story is likely included twice in the page."

Comment: It looks like this message triggers if you try loading the same script twice. It might have to do with the way you reload the story preview: the AMP code thinks you're loading all the scripts one more time.

Comment: Yes, since amp-story and other tags are custom ones, that are being registered every time, but even if I don't reload the whole iframe content but only its body, the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the document is evaluated twice and hence the message. One possibility to resolve this is to replace the iframe entirely. For example, create a wrapper DIV:

```
<div id=iframe_wrapper></div>
```

And fill in your iframe when it gets updated:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_wrapper").innerHTML = "<iframe ..."
// find the iframe and insert content
```